# Ubuntu 12.04 opening dialog hangs too long when opening files,folders, anything?

Tags: 12.04, files, directory, panel

Every time i open any file, or folder, basically anything, there is an opening dialog on my panel, like Opening this and that.

And even when file is opened, opening dialog hangs there for another 5-10 seconds.

Is there a way to remove, or prevent opening dialog?

[image]

Take a look at screenshot. I clicked on Home, and my home folder is opened instantly. But there is a tab that says "Opening aleksandar" and hangs there for another 6-7 seconds. Can i prevent this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer at the end, it's not a fix for opening dialog hanging too long, but it's workaround to remove opening dialog.

open nautilus.desktop

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

and set

```
StartupNotify=false
```

Now when opening folders i don't have opening notification and no loading circle on mouse. Problem solved.